# Python: Save a list and recover it for AI learning application

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have an application that requires saving a list as it grows. This is a step towards doing AI learning stuff. Anyway here is my code:

```
vocab = ["cheese", "spam", "eggs"]

word = raw_input()

vocab.append(word)
```

However when the code is run the finished `vocab` will return to just being *cheese, spam* and *eggs*.
 How can I make whatever I append to the list stay there permenantly even when windows CMD is closed and I return to the code editing stage. Is this clear enough??
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You're looking into the more general problem of object persistence.  There are bazillions of ways to do this.  If you're just starting out, the easiest way to save/restore data structures in Python is using the pickle module.  As you get more advanced, there are different methods and they all have their trade-offs...which you'll learn when you need to.

Comment: ok object persistance I didn't know what it was called I can now google it!!

Answer (score 4):

Look into [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

With it, you can serialize a Python data structure and then reload it like so:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> vocab =["cheese", "spam", "eggs"]
>>> outf=open('vocab.pkl','wb')
>>> pickle.dump(vocab,outf)
>>> outf.close()
>>> quit()
```

Python interpreter is now exited, restart Python and reload the data structure:

```
abd-pb:~ andrew$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> pklf=open('vocab.pkl','rb')
>>> l=pickle.load(pklf)
>>> l
['cheese', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

Comment: (LOL) -- you beat me to it by *seconds* :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and files, something like this:

```
import json

#write the data to a file
outfile = open("dumpFile", 'w')
json.dump(vocab, outfile)

#read the data back in
with open("dumpFile") as infile:
    newVocab = json.load(infile)
```

This has the advantage of being a plain text file, so you can view the data stored in it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pickle, but as a technique it's limited to python programs. The normal way to deal with persistent data is to write it to a file. Just read your word list from a regular text file (one word per line), and write out an updated word list later. Later you can learn how to keep this kind of information in a database (more powerful but less flexible than a file).

You can happily program for years without actually needing pickle, but you can't do without file i/o and databases.

PS. Keep it simple: You don't need to mess with json, pickle or any other structured format unless and until you NEED structure.

Comment: Yes, JSON (unlike pickle) is quite portable across platforms and languages. My point was the relative complexity of such solutions. For a beginning programmer, the first step should be direct file i/o.

Comment: I don't find pickle to be all that complicated. It is not cross platform or cross language, but it is not complicated.